# Adding SRV record - How to?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting, srv-record

yes I now that I can have my domain reseller done that but my reseller `domain.com` fails to add it and when I ask them about how to add a srv record they told me to transfer my domain to `zoneedit.com`. Therefore they are useless in this case.

so my question is if there is any way/workaround/nasty hack to get those SRV records added? via VPS or via a free-edit-DNS-record thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as domain hosted on domain.com and as long as domain.com does not support SRV records, there is no workaround.

Just follow the advice you given by domain.com - move your zone to another provider, there's no problem with that.

Zoneedit is a popular choice, there are others as well - see [this list of free DNS providers](http://talkdns.info/list).

Before you sign-up, check if provider you choose supports SRV records (zoneedit does).

Answer (score 0):

FYI: I use mydomain.com, which I believe is owned by Domain.com. Although they don't offer SRV as an option in their dropdown, I was able to get my SRV records added by using the help real-time chat option. The technician added my four SRV records: _carddav._tcp, _carddavs._tcp, _caldav._tcp, & _caldavs._tcp.